# How to force Selenium to continue to next process without waiting to complete loading a page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Normally, after navingating to an url, Selenium WebDriver waits to complete the page to continue to next process (next line of code). If the process takes long time then it will throw timeout exception. I don't want to wait too long. After 10 seconds navigating to an url I don't want to wait until it completed.

```
        using (IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver())
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.mywebsite.com"); //takes a long time here. More than 40 seconds to complete whole page
            //here I don't want to wait too long
            // <input type="text" id="tp-test-selenium" />
            var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("tp-test-selenium"));  //I should be able to access this text input without waiting 40 seconds
        }
```

I want to continue getting element even if the page is not fully loaded.

Comment: Without loading page fully how could you get the element??? Is this make sense??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Yes. Loading image with ajax. I have tested in my browser displayed by Selenium

Comment: Just clear to me, you don't to wait for loading image with ajax or loading full page??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Both of them. If your browser loads a page it sometimes doesn't load fully especially because of poor internet connection. The css, javascript file or others are not loaded. And mostly, most elements are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set page load timeout to desired number of seconds.

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Then probably wrap GotoUrl() with try/catch

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver())
{
    try
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.mywebsite.com"); //takes a long time here. More than 40 seconds to complete whole page
    }
    catch(WebPageTimeoutException e)
    {
        //Log it or not
    }
    finally
    {
        // It will perform your steps either if page loaded correctly during timeout set or after timeout expired
        //here I don't want to wait too long
        // <input type="text" id="tp-test-selenium" />
        var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("tp-test-selenium"));  //I should be able to access this text input without waiting 40 seconds
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I'll give it a try.